# How to plot multiple subplots using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a problem where i am given the an image and have to recreate this image using python and matplotlib, sklearn, numpy. Following is the image:

[image: Result Wanted Picture]

Here is the code i have written so far in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
print(type(iris))
print(iris['target_names'])
print(iris['data'])
print(iris['target'])
print(iris['DESCR'])
print(iris['feature_names'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)


iris = load_iris()
data = np.array(iris['data'])
targets = np.array(iris['target'])

cd = {0: 'r', 1: 'b', 2: 'g'}

cols = np.array([cd[target] for target in targets])

ax1.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c=cols)
ax2.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 2], c=cols)
plt.show()
```

I am completely lost and really need help to get past this one, i only get the first 2 subplots right. Any advice would be very helpful as i have been trying to figure this one out a few days now.

Comment: Check out [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), It is used for plotting data and presenting it similar to your provided image

Comment: Use [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html#subplot-example)

Comment: "i only get the first 2 subplots right" You are creating only 2 subplots, how many of them do you want to get right?

Comment: Note that there are 2 features being used for each subplot. i.e.The first 2 subplots
came from our example of plotting the iris dataset. This is a permutation problem. From
4 features choose 2 which equals 12 choices in total. That is why there are 12 subplots in
total. That is the only bit of advice i get to help me, so 12 in total

Comment: seaborn's [pairplot](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjY2Pyj-vDkAhUBT98KHfc3Dj0QFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fseaborn.pydata.org%2Fgenerated%2Fseaborn.pairplot.html&usg=AOvVaw1gKcQdBF3qbrd_nalivUhM)

Comment: There are only 2 subplots in your code.

Comment: loved using seaborn's pairs, thanks @AbishekAditya

Comment: and @QuangHoung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hopefully explains exactly how to create the requested images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

fig, subs = plt.subplots(4,3) #setting the shape of the figure in one line as opposed to creating 12 variables 

iris = load_iris() ##code as per the example 
data = np.array(iris['data'])
targets = np.array(iris['target'])

cd = {0:'r',1:'b',2:"g"}
cols = np.array([cd[target] for target in targets])


# Row 1 

subs[0][0].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[0][1].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,2], c=cols)
subs[0][2].scatter(data[:,0], data[:,3], c=cols)

# Row 2 

subs[1][0].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[1][1].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,2], c=cols)
subs[1][2].scatter(data[:,1], data[:,3], c=cols)

# Row 3 

subs[2][0].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[2][1].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[2][2].scatter(data[:,2], data[:,3], c=cols)

#Row 4 

subs[3][0].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,0], c=cols)
subs[3][1].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,1], c=cols)
subs[3][2].scatter(data[:,3], data[:,2], c=cols)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 6))

# ax is a 2d array with shape (4, 3), it can be sliced just like a numpy array 

for row in range(4):
    for col in range(3):
        ax[row][col].scatter(x, y, c='color you want')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @Wynand Roberts any questions?

Comment: Thanks allot, no Questions

Answer (score 0):

One way to get a figure with according sublots would be

```
fig, subs = plt.subplots(4,3)
```

subs is then a 2d array of the ares, so you can do:

```
subs[0][0].scatter(x,y)
```